# How to find the metrics definitions for azure logic apps?I am trying the following approach

Tags: azure

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subsriptionid}/resourceGroups/{resource group}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{work flow name}/metricDefinitions?api-version=2014-04-01&$filter=
I am trying the above url but its not able to find the metrics definitions. But for all other like data factories i am able to find the metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the **[Azure Monitor REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931943.aspx)** for retrieving the metrics and insights related for Azure resources such as Azure Logic App.

API Reference: 
[List metrics definitions for a resource with Azure Monitor REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt743621.aspx)

For retrieving metric definitions for Azure Logic App, issue GET request with the below sample REST API.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resource_group_name}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{logic_app_name}/providers/microsoft.insights/metricdefinitions?api-version={api-version}&$filter={filter}
```

Sample response:

```
...
      "name": {
        "value": "RunsStarted",
        "localizedValue": "Runs Started"
      },
      "startTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "endTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "unit": "Count",
      "primaryAggregationType": "Total",
      "metricAvailabilities": [
        {
          "timeGrain": "PT1M",
          "retention": "P30D"
        },
        {
          "timeGrain": "PT1H",
          "retention": "P30D"
        }
      ],
...
```

Note: Tested working as expected with API version = **2016-03-01**

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if this helps and if you appreciate the effort of helping

Comment: but i am not able to get table end points and table info it only giving me the time grains and retention.

Answer (score 1):

For retrieving metric values for Azure Logic App, make a GET request with REST API.

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{2}/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?api-version=2016-06-01&$filter={filter like what you want to get from the metrics}